# How to fit a 18x18 table on 1 page?

Tags: tables

I have the following code, however the table does not fit on 1 page as it is a 18x18 table. I tried doing it in landscape, but then it still does not fit on one page. Also I tried to make the font smaller, but this doesn't get the desired result also. My code is the following:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{table}[H] \centering 
  \caption{18x18 correlation matrix} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccccccccccccccccc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
.....
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: remove the `\begin{scriptsize}` it does nothing as it is outside the table, use `\scriptsize` or `\tiny` or whatever font size you need _inside_ `\begin{table}`, but if the font really has to be that small have a thought for your readers and consider using a larger font but showing the data over two or three pages.

Comment: `\hline` should never be followed by `\\ ` that is adding spurious enmpty rows which is why you are needing negative space, delete all those `\\[..]`

Comment: How wide and tall is text block?

Comment: Clear. Thank you for your response. 1 more question about the \tiny inside \begin{table} - how do you mean this exactly?

Comment: @ Mico: the text has a width of 0.0000

Comment: Off-topic: Your'e trying to visualize a 324-entry matrix as a table? I don't think you're choosing the right tool for the job. Think about the readers who will get lost in the hundreds of entries ... are all numbers really important? I used to visualze 1024x1024 matrices and bigger by using a `spy` plot in a regular space of a figure.

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable and also add some entries to your table? How wide are the entries of each cell? Which documentclass do you use? ...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{lscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\footnotesize
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
\[
  \begin{array}{*{18}r}
1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000
  \end{array}
\]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This helped tremendously, exactly what I needed. I just added the headings for both the rows and columns. Any idea how to specify the border for the first column (in which the headings for the rows are stated)?

Comment: @Famke  change `*{18}r`  by `l|*{18}r`  to have an extra l column at the start separated by a vertical rul

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

With due apologies to @DavidCarlisle I could not resist adding color !!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\minuscellcolor}{}
\def\minuscellcolor\ignorespaces{%
  % \ignorespaces not really needed, because \@ifnextchar gobbles spaces
  \@ifnextchar1{\cellcolor{blue!20}}{}%
}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\minuscellcolor}c}
\makeatother
\begin{document}  
\begin{table}  
  \footnotesize
  \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC}  
    \toprule  
1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000&0.0000\\
0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&0.0000&1.0000\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: colour is OK but a correlation matrix is math, it should be array not tabular.